# "ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyModule_Type"" (rust-cpython) while cross-compiling library to android

Tags: python, android, rust, cross-compiling, buildozer

I'm creating an android app, for which I'm developing a rust library. I'm building the app in python with `kivy`, using `buildozer`. And for the library, I'm using the `cpython` crate.

I get the errors while cross-compiling from x86_64 using Linux to `aarch64-linux-android` with the following command:

```bash
cargo build --target aarch64-linux-android
```

When I compile without the `--release` tag, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/feluk6174/python/lib_test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyModule_Type" referenced by "/data/data/org.test.doxa_test/files/app/doxa_api.so"...
```

And with the `--release` tag:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/feluk6174/python/lib_test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 26, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_OverflowError" referenced by "/data/data/org.test.doxa_test/files/app/doxa_api.so"...
```

### Environment

I used the parts of [this](https://mozilla.github.io/firefox-browser-architecture/experiments/2017-09-21-rust-on-android.html) tutorial where rust and the NDK are set up.

After that tutorial, I got the following error:

```
ld: error: unable to find library -lgcc
```

After doing the fix proposed in [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/85806#issuecomment-1096266946), it compiled, but after running it on my phone I got the errors mentioned above.

### Rust code

The code for the library (`lib.rs`) is the following:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::{Python, PyResult};


py_module_initializer!(doxa_api, doxa_api, PyInit_doxa_api, |py, m | {
    m.add(py, "__doc__", "This module is implemented in Rust")?;
    m.add(py, "test", py_fn!(py, 
        test(a: u8, b:u8) -> PyResult<u8>{
            Ok(a as u8+b as u8)

        }
    ))?;
    Ok(())
});
```

The `cargo.toml` file is the following:

```ini
[package]
name = "doxa_api"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"


[lib]
name = "doxa_api"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
cpython = {version = "*",  features = ["extension-module"]}
```

And the `.cargo/config.toml`:

```ini
[target.aarch64-linux-android]
ar = "/home/feluk6174/rust/doxa_api/NDK/arm64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "/home/feluk6174/rust/doxa_api/NDK/arm64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang"

[target.armv7-linux-androideabi]
ar = "/home/feluk6174/rust/doxa_api/NDK/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
linker = "/home/feluk6174/rust/doxa_api/NDK/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang"

[target.i686-linux-android]
ar = "/home/feluk6174/rust/doxa_api/NDK/x86/bin/i686-linux-android-ar"
linker = "/home/feluk6174/rust/doxa_api/NDK/x86/bin/i686-linux-android-clang"
```

### Python code

The file `doxa_api.so` is in the same folder as the following code.
And the python code is the following:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
import kivy.uix.screenmanager
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import random

import doxa_api

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()

        sm.add_widget(Screen(name = "screen"))
        
        return sm

class Screen(kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_box = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        self.add_widget(self.main_box)

        self.button = Button(text = "try", on_release = self.test)
        self.main_box.add_widget(self.button)


    def test(self, t):
        print("a")
        
        self.button.text = str(doxa_api.test(1, random.randint(0,254)))
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### Versions

I'm using `python3.10.9`. The `kivy`version is `2.1.0` and the `buildozer`version is `1.5.0`. The rust version is `1.67.0`.

Comment: I've given up and just made the program that I wanted to build in rust in python. But if someone is having a similar problem, it seems that it has to do with the fact that I didn't pass to cargo/rust-cpython a python interpreter built for android.